# Cobertura not generating coverage report

Tags: gradle, groovy, junit, cobertura, test-coverage

I am trying to use cobertura to generate coverage report for my groovy project. I am using gradle to install cobertura ang junit 5

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'net.saliman.cobertura' version '2.5.4'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Running the `cobertura` task generates an empty coverage report (0 classes and no  coverage). The jUnit report shows the correct unit test which have been run.

Gralde output

```
> Task :coberturaReport UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileGroovy
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes

> Task :instrument
Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file

> Task :copyCoberturaDatafile
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileTestGroovy
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses
> Task :test

> Task :generateCoberturaReport
Cobertura 2.1.1 - GNU GPL License (NO WARRANTY) - See COPYRIGHT file
Report time: 150ms

> Task :performCoverageCheck SKIPPED
> Task :cobertura

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 11s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
07:53:16: Task execution finished 'cobertura'.
```

What confuses me is the line  `> Task :performCoverageCheck SKIPPED` Is this the problem? How do I enable the coverage check?

Answer (score 0):

After enabling --debug, I found that it is not instrumenting any classes. Adding `coverageDirs = ["${buildDir}/classes/groovy/main"]` in cobertura as below solved the issues for me.

```
cobertura {
    coverageFormats = ["html", "xml"]
    coverageIgnoreTrivial true
    coverageCheckHaltOnFailure false
    coverageDirs = ["${buildDir}/classes/groovy/main"]
}
```